# How is a single month duration defined on a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, users, dates

A user profile on any of the Stack Exchange websites shows the age of the account in terms of number of years and months.

> [image] Member for 1 year, 4 months

How is a single month duration defined and calculated?

- Is 30 days considered a single month?
- Is a month counted from date to date (from one month to next)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>NOTE: Since these labels will change over time, I've archived the profile pages to the Wayback Machine.</sup>

It seems to jump from 60 days to 2 months:

- [This user](http://web.archive.org/web/20190710084332/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/530895/rex) is a "Member for 60 days"
- [This user](http://web.archive.org/web/20190710084352/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/530409/gingerman) is a "Member for 2 months", even though they registered on **May 11th** 00:07 (UTC), which is slightly less than 2 months ago.

The cut off between two and three months:

- [This user](http://web.archive.org/web/20190710084409/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/513719/maycon-mesquita) from April 13th is a "Member for 2 months"
- [This user](http://web.archive.org/web/20190710084423/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/513052/han-luo) from **April 12th** is a "Member for 3 months".

Going further,

- [This user](http://web.archive.org/web/20190710084436/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/493079/hernan-ramirez) from **March 13th** is a "Member for 4 months".

This would suggest that your guess "Is 30 days considered a single month?" is right. But a year is 365 days, not 12 months:

- [This user](http://web.archive.org/web/20190710084451/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/395702/ash), registered July 12th last year, is a "Member for 11 months".

Comment: Maybe the implementation  is still this accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248/578411

Comment: Interesting, but that code won't produce the "1 year, 4 months" from Nimesh's example.

Comment: We need someone with code access to dig up the implementation. Let's hope it is not part of `HandleSuccess`

Comment: @Glorfindel Are you talking in reference to my [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema?tab=profile) profile? (The place where I picked the example from)?

Comment: I meant the example in your question. I didn't know it was from your own profile.